# Opening a file in Eclipse using Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to write a method that opens a file (e.g. XML) with the Eclipse XML editor.

I have an XML file in my workspace. Alternative route: *right mouse click on the file > open with > xml editor*. I would like to achieve this programmatically using Java.

Comment: So you want to write an Eclipse plugin that can open a file in an editor?

Comment: Can I do it without writing a plugin?

Comment: This is too broad. This requires an Eclipse plug-in. Have you written a plug-in? Have you determined what `IFile` needs to be opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following statement to run a command line command:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("eclipse.exe C:/path/to/your/file.xml");
```

Make sure that your Eclipse executable is part of your system's `PATH` variable or use the complete path in the command.

Comment: name of the library that I must import?

Comment: `java.lang.Runtime` is part of the standard library. [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse is you default XML program you can go for:

```
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:/Users/exampleUser/Desktop/test.xml"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Otherwise go for TimoSta's solution.